# How to save checked items of CheckedListBox to retrieve them later?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, checkedlistbox

Controls:

- 1 ComboBox
- 1 CheckedListBox

ComboBox:

- Items: 110
- Events:

  - SelectedIndexChanged: Each time the selected index change the items collection of CheckedListBox change

Functions:

```
private void cbSubCategories_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch(cbSubCategories.Text)
    {
        clbSubCategories2.Items.Clear();
        case "Category 1":
            AddSubCategory(0, 15);
            break;
        //etc.
    }
}

private void AddSubCategories2(int from, int to)
{
    for (int i = from; i < to; i++)
        clbSubCategories2.Items.Add(strSubCategories2[i]);
}
```

CheckedListBox

- Items: Depends on which item selected in ComboBox
- Events:

  - ItemCheck: Add the checked item to a list

Functions:

```
List<string> checkedItems = new List<string>();

private void clbSubCategories2_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    int idx = 0;
    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
        checkedItems.Add(clbSubCategories2.Items[e.Index].ToString());
    else if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked)
    {
        if (checkedItems.Contains(clbSubCategories2.Items[e.Index].ToString()))
        {
            idx = checkedItems.IndexOf(clbSubCategories2.Items[e.Index].ToString());
            checkedItems.RemoveAt(idx);
        }
    }
}
```

Now lets say I select item **A** on ComboBox so the CheckedListBox have now Collection Items **Q**. I check 2 items from **Q** and then I select different item from ComboBox **B** so the Collection Items of CheckedListBox (**W**) change too. Now if I go back to **A**, the Collection Items **Q** is again retrieved back. I want now the 2 items that I checked to be retrieved too. How I can do that?

My idea was something like that (I add this code inside cbSubCategories_SelectedIndexChanged at the end) but it throws this exception `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.`:

```
int x = 0;
foreach (string item in clbSubCategories2.Items)
{
    foreach (string item2 in checkedItems)
    {
        if (item2 == item)
            clbSubCategories2.SetItemChecked(x, true);
    }
    x++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you do it upon `SelectedIndexChanged` event of your comboBox. That's where you are re-binding everytime your CheckedListBox.

so inside `AddSubCategories2(int from, int to)`, after adding items to your CheckedListBox, again iterate through the items of it and mark all those which exist in  the checkedItems list.

```
private void AddSubCategories2(int from, int to)
{
       for (int i = from; i < to; i++)
        clbSubCategories2.Items.Add(strSubCategories2[i]);

       if(checkedItems!=null)
          foreach(string item in checkedItems)
          { 
              int index=  clbSubCategories2.FindStringExact(item);
              if(index>-1)
                clbSubCategories2.SetItemChecked(index, true);
          }
}
```

Comment: sorry forgot to mention I add my code there but it throw exception `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.`

Comment: ofcourse, you cannot iterate over the same collection and modify it, see my code.

Comment: It throw me the same exception

Comment: no way, you are not even iterating over your checkedboxlist item collection anymore, did you remove that earlier foreach loop of yours?? try the exact code that i've posted

Comment: Yes I removed it... Now my code is exactly like above plus your code on the AddSubCategories2 function.

Comment: the exception throw on `in`

Comment: if the exception 'Collection was modified..' is coming in the foreach loop that i wrote, at in then it simply means, checkedItems collection is modified, either an item is added, updated,deleted from it, which clearly is not being done in the code which is written here. you sure at your end, ur using exact code?? as I just tested it out, and it works fine

Comment: I don't know why it throws this exception but i changed foreach to for and it works

Comment: anyways, it appeared to be a super simple situation but turned out to be a little hazy one. +1 to your question